# Remove "virtual" keyword in binding Xamarin library by using metadata.xml

Tags: android, binding, xamarin, metadata

I'm binding a Xamarin Library from Java and it generates 1 wrong function.
The keyword should be **override** but currently it is **virtual**.

> // Metadata.xml XPath method reference: path="/api/package[@name='com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.tileprovider']/class[@name='MapTileLayerBase.CacheTask']/method[@name='doInBackground' and count(parameter)=1 and parameter[1][@type='java.lang.Object...']]"
> [Register ("doInBackground", "([Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Void;", "GetDoInBackground_arrayLjava_lang_Object_Handler")]
>
> protected **virtual** unsafe global::Java.Lang.Object DoInBackground
> (params global:: Java.Lang.Object[] p0)

I need to change **virtual** to **override** but I don't know how to do that.

I found some comments on the internet say that I should try this one:

```
<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.tileprovider']/class[@name='MapTileLayerBase.CacheTask']/method[@name='doInBackground']" name="virtual">false</attr>
```

I tried but it didn't work.

Do you know how to change it?

Comment: Have you found the solution?

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.tileprovider']/class[@name='MapTileLayerBase.CacheTask']/method[@name='doInBackground']" name="managedOverride">override</attr>
```

or more hacky way if previous step doesn't work:

```
<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.tileprovider']/class[@name='MapTileLayerBase.CacheTask']/method[@name='doInBackground']" name="final">true</attr>
<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.tileprovider']/class[@name='MapTileLayerBase.CacheTask']/method[@name='doInBackground']" name="visibility">protected override</attr>
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to set `final` to `true` in the `Metadata.xml` mapping:

```
<attr 
   path="/api/package[@name='com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.tileprovider']/class[@name='MapTileLayerBase.CacheTask']/method[@name='doInBackground']"
   name="final">true</attr>
```

This effectively removes the `virtual` keyword from the method signature, and doesn't add the `final` keyword either. Strange behavior, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you need this method exposed in your API? You could use approach from this thread http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/1871/binding-java-library-with-parameter-type-void and just remove this method. Usually methods like this are not explicitly used from the outside.

Answer (score 0):

In

1. in obj/Debug/generated/src find MCW for that class (com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.tileprovider.cs)
2. copy that file to Additions/ folder and include it into project.
3. change BuildAction to Compile if neccessary
4. change virtual to override
5. that class from process